# Linux directory starting with dot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, directory

Is there anything special about directories which start with a dot `.` in Linux (Ubuntu), such as `~/.vim`?
Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Files and directories whose names begin with a dot (`.`) by default are not displayed in directory listings by the standard command `ls`.  Therefore, they are traditionally used to store settings, preferences, *etc*..  Directory `~/.vim` in particular surely contains personal preferences and settings for the text editor `vim`.

There are also two special directory names in this class: the directory named simply `.` is an alias for the same directory in which it appears (a self reference), and the directory named `..` refers to the parent directory of `.`.

Many graphical file browsers ignore the convention of hiding file names beginning with a `.`, so it is not necessarily correct any longer to call these files "hidden".  Nevertheless, that terminology persists.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. When I wanted to install 'rails vim' which is for editing rails code using Vim, all I had to do was to download a zip file (`rails.zip`) and unzip it inside `.vim` directory. Does that mean every time I start the program Vim it goes to folder `.vim` and loads the settings inside that directory? Is that how installation works in Linux? Just copying files in a correct directory? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, every time you start `vim`, it reads your personal settings from files in subdirectory `.vim` of your home directory.  This is a common behavior of UNIX programs, but it is by no means universal.

Comment: In a sense, yes, software installation for the most part does simply involve dropping files in the correct places, but your particular experience was a special case.  What you installed was not actually a program, but *only* Vim settings.  Most Linux distributions have one form or another of system for managing software "packages", and this is the preferred mode for installing software that will be accessible to all users of the system.  Ubuntu is such a distribution, but I cannot advise you about details.

Answer (score 6):

In UNIX-like environments, a filename preceded by a dot indicates a hidden file. It's mainly a mechanism to decrease clutter in directory listings. You can get a listing of hidden files by passing the -a parameter to ls

Answer (score 1):

Those are hidden. You'd need to apply extra effort to see them.