# Where is .meteor directory in the project in Ubuntu?

Tags: meteor

I need to add some packages in the `package` file inside the `.meteor` folder.
This did work on Windows, but I recently switched to linux. The project now has folders `client` and `server` along with `package.json` file. Is there an alternate to it?
The `package.json` file doesn't seem to be the one I'm looking for since I didn't see any of the packages listed.

Comment: Ran it multiple times, with no results

Comment: The folder is probably hidden in the directory .. can you try ctrl+h?

Comment: Do you run `ls` to show all the files? Try with `ls -a`. The `.meteor` and `.gitignore` files are hidden as their names imply.

Comment: Yes they were hidden. Thanks!

Comment: You can also use `Ctrl + H` if you're using the graphical file explorer.

Answer (score 2):

Probably directory is there but you don't see it in listing.

Files (and directories) starting with `.` (`.git`, `.meteor` etc) are considered as hidden and by default are not displayed in listing (read more: [Linux directory starting with dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28972757/linux-directory-starting-with-dot))

You can still do actions with them (eg. `cd .meteor`). To show them in listing do as Kyll mentioned in his comment.

Answer (score 1):

. files are in Linux are hidden files.

So using ls -la command you can see those hidden file in Linux.

You can also use sublime text that will also show your hidden files.